# product of matrices, and its norm

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

I have a product of matrices $\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n} a_i$, If $b$ is an eigenvalue of $a_i$ for any $i$, then $|b|<1$.

(1) Under what norm or condition, $\|\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n} a_i\|<r<1$

(2) If I had infinite such matrices, $\|\prod\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i\|<r<1$ true for some norm?

(3) What if all the matrices are diagonalizable? In that case, will I get (1) and (2) as desired in some norm?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the [vector induced norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Matrix_norms_induced_by_vector_norms) can work? If $b$ is an eigenvalue of $a_i$ implies that $|b|<1$, then the largest eigenvalue of $a_i$, call it $\tilde{a}_i$ should also be $|\tilde{a}_i|$<1. 
Taking a look specifically at the statement in the wiki page:

"Any induced operator norm is a submultiplicative matrix norm $\lVert AB \rVert < \lVert A \rVert \lVert B \rVert $ ".

Thus, in the vector induced norm, we should be able to say that
\begin{equation}
\lVert \prod_{i=1}^{n} a_i \rVert <  \prod_{i=1}^{n} \lVert a_i \rVert < \lVert \tilde{a} \rVert^{n}<1,
\end{equation}
where $\tilde{a}$ is the largest eigenvalue of all the $\tilde{a}_i$'s.

I think this applies for all three points.

Comment: How did you write $\prod_{i=1}^{n} \lVert a_i \rVert < \lVert \tilde{a} \rVert^{n}<1$? from the fact that $\|Ax\|=\|\lambda x\|\le |\lambda| \|x\|?$

Comment: If $\lVert a_i \rVert = sup\lbrace \lVert a_i x \rVert : x \in K^m \, \text{with}\,  \lVert x \rVert =1\rbrace$,  where $ K^m$ is a vector space with a norm defined on it. Then $\lVert a_i \rVert< \tilde{a}_i$. Then we define $\tilde{a}$ as the largest of the $\tilde{a}_i$'s.  Hence $\tilde{a}_i < \tilde{a}$ for all $i$. (Apologies for edit, accidentally commenting before finishing)